# SSIS: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source.

Tags: ssis

I know there is similar question, but it didn`t helped me.
When I execute a package data flow task fails with the error:
"Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available."

I refreshed the source component, the destination components also. The table do exist in database. I tried with setting some parameters like "Always Use Default Code Page" to true but didn`t helped.

Connections are also ok.

Any idea?

Comment: Where are you executing your package?  From SSDT/Visual Studio or on the server?

Comment: In Visual Studio. When I execute it via job on the server everything works fine. But I want to monitor the data, I enabled some data viewers, I want to debug something.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions issue.  Try, running Visual Studio as administrator or if that doesn't work, make sure your Windows Account has access to the data you require in SQL Server.